# Why won't the Thunderbolt Firmware Update v1 ever install on a Macbook Pro 2011?

Tags: updates, macbook, thunderbolt

Software update keeps telling me that Thunderbolt Firmware Update v1 needs installing, and that it needs a reboot - so I duly oblige, and it goes through the motions. But it keeps telling me it needs to apply this update - all the other updates work fine.

And it's not even as though there's much hardware to buy to make use of the Thunderbolt port either !!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EFI won't install ANY firmware upgrade if it checks the computer is not connected to an external power supply (magsafe).

I'd bet you were trying to update without connecting to your wall power socket.

:)

Comment: Very strange - I do all software updates without being plugged in. It warns me, but I just go ahead. And it works..... and it appeared to work for the thunderbolt update too, except it never went away.... until I plugged it in the wall! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck all other updates, and leave the Thunderbolt firmware update checked.

Click "Install 1 Item".

The firmware update should start downloading (~63MB). It'll install and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: Some of Apple's firmware updates don't get installed automatically, Software Update just drops a program to do it into /Applications/Utilities, which you then need to execute yourself.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks.... I do click to install, but you never know!